I need to split a column based on content then apply content with out comma to previous rows using Python
I am using Python in a Amazon_Conda3 JupyterLab Notebook. I extracted data from a document using Textract TABLES. I am iterating through the tables in the document and need to format and present the data as a tabular data structure.
The problem is that the tables have lastName, firstName above a subtotal row describing their position. Like this:



Description
Hrs Worked




Shmo, Joe
160.00


Sr. Software Engineer
160.00



My final output has to look like:



Labor Category
Last Name
FirstName
Hrs Worked




Sr. Software Engineer
Shmo
Joe
160.00



This repeats for different labor categories within a single table. I hate to put all my eggs into one basket where I am counting on a comma in a column because it could be really problematic, but I am pretty sure its my only option at this point.
I am new to Python and to Jupyter Notebooks and to data science as a whole. In fact, I am pretty green when it comes to Python syntax and it's built in features; however, I have been programming in other languages for more than 25 years.
My gut says to copy the tables as separate tabular data structures based on a comma rule, trim them out, then combine them to get my final data structure as a pandas data frame. But that approach seems pretty kludgey to me.
Any thoughts?
